# How do I rename a Blazor WASM project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I renamed sln, csproj and namespace but am getting these three errors which I didn't have prior to renaming.

```
   /App.razor(66,66): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MainLayout' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS0246) 
  /obj/Debug/net5.0/Razor/App.razor.g.cs(155,155): Error CS1662: Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type (CS1662)
   /App.razor(37,37): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MainLayout' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS0246)
```

Comment: Did you change the `_Imports.razor` file?

Comment: I did , I changed the namespace there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a project template from within Visual Studio

[image]

This will let you "re-create" your project with a new name, it will keep everything you have but rename some namespaces to your new name.

Also helpful if you need to create "project templates" to be re-used in your organization

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem until I renamed the namespace to match the project name